# Is it worth copying data into a MEMORY table for use?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, in-memory

I'm building a webservice that requires some lookup tables.  These are stored in MariaDB. I expect the primary table to start off with a few hundred values but as time goes on, some will become inactive and others will be added.  Only active values are needed for the service, the rest are for audit purposes.

As a consequence, I am considering holding a copy of tables in the MEMORY engine and only loading it with the required subset of records needed and refreshing it periodically with changes.

Does this seem like a sensible route for reducing query overheads and retrieval times for my web service? Is there another potential solution that would be more fitting?

Comment: InnoDB keeps working data-set in memory by default. It's controlled via `innodb_buffer_pool` variable setting. Short answer - no, it's not worth the hassle. MySQL tries to do lots of query optimization for you out of the box, you just have to know what you're using (which engine) and what to configure for better performance. InnoDB will be fast enough, I have a medium-sized project that has around 600 million records in one table, InnoDB is selecting the values just fine and quick.

Comment: Good to know - happy for you to put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

@N.Bs comment :

> InnoDB keeps working data-set in memory by default. It's controlled
>   via innodb_buffer_pool variable setting. Short answer - no, it's not
>   worth the hassle. MySQL tries to do lots of query optimization for you
>   out of the box, you just have to know what you're using (which engine)
>   and what to configure for better performance. InnoDB will be fast
>   enough, I have a medium-sized project that has around 600 million
>   records in one table, InnoDB is selecting the values just fine and
>   quick.